# How can I check if NGEN service is running?

Tags: windows, service, ngen

I need to use [NGEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to precompile my CLR assemblies. I use the queue option to make that the request are processed by the "Native image service".

I need to ensure that the service is running, otherwise I will execute the optimization synchronously.

I tried the following in a **Win8.1 x64** machine, and it failed.

```
C:\>sc.exe query clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

Do you know what is the service name?

Comment: `sc.exe query type= service` (need the extra space, admin console) will list the running names, iirc ngen only runs when in use.

Comment: It is just like the error message says, it is not an installed service.  It gets started dynamically, the odds that it is running are exceedingly low.   You already know the service names, the executable is mscorsvw.exe and there are 4 versions of it.  Do avoid asking an XY question.

Comment: @HansPassant: Is there any chance that I execute a queued NGEN and it does not work? I tried it in a Windows10 RC and did not work because it seems that the NGEN service is not present. Is there any chance that the NGEN service is not present in other SO?